# Passing arguments to a BroadcastReceiver through an Intent in Android

Tags: android

I have an application, which sets an alarm using AlarmManager, which starts another Activity when it goes off.  The AlarmManager takes a PendingIntent and spawns a BroadcastReceiver class when the specified time comes.  I'm wondering whether there is any way that I can pass arguments to this BroadcastReceiver through the Intent object which goes into PendingIntent?

Basically what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
Intent my_intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, my_intent, 0);
my_intent.putExtra("arg1", arg1);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000), pendingIntent);
```

and I'd like to be able to retrieve arg1 in the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive(Context, Intent) method.  I figured that the local variable my_intent would be the second parameter passed on to onReceive by the PendingIntent, but apparently that's not quite right.  Is it possible to pass parameters between an Activity and a BroadcastReceiver in this fashion (using Intent.putExtra()) or should I use a ContentProvider instead?

Thanks!

Iva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an application, which sets an
>   alarm using AlarmManager, which starts
>   another Activity when it goes off.

That is bad form. Do not pop up activities unannounced like this without a *very* good reason (e.g., an incoming phone call). What if the user is in the middle of doing something, like TXTing or playing a game or trying to tap numbers for a phone menu?

> Is it possible to pass parameters
>   between an Activity and a
>   BroadcastReceiver in this fashion
>   (using Intent.putExtra())

Yes. However, bear in mind that you will want to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when you create your `PendingIntent`, to ensure that any new extras you supply on the Intent actually get used.

Comment: Ah yes, I misspoke; I'm using the Alarm as an avenue to invoke a particular activity at a particular time, and when the alarm goes off, I create a notification which the user can then drop down whenever convenient and only then invoke the activity, so that I don't disturb whatever they happen to be doing.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hmm, adding the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as a flag when getting the PendingIntent doesn't seem to change anything;  I'm still not getting the extras from the intent in my original Activity to the intent passed to the onReceive

Comment: Are you calling putExtra() before creating the PendingIntent? I don't know when PendingIntent serializes the Intent, but if it does it right away, putExtra() calls after creating the PendingIntent would have no effect.

Comment: I'm calling putExtra() after creating the PendingIntent.  I'm populating all of the extras inside of an OnClickListener, and thus they're may not be ready when the PendingIntent is first created.  Perhaps I would be better off using a ContentProvider

Comment: You're right!  Populating the intent before wrapping it in a PendingIntent worked.  Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, but I was already populating the Intent first before wrapping it in a PendingIntent.  But the answer to my problem was, as pointed out above, that I needed to use the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag.  Once I set the flag, it worked!  I hope this helps others.
-Jeff

Comment: I was having this same issue and the flag totally did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
int code=1;
Intent i2 = new Intent(StartAlarm);
i2.putExtra("_id",code);

class test extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        int i=arg1.getIntExtra("_id",-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it is possible to pass any data of basic Java type and Serializable/Parceable types in the extras of an Intent wrapped around a PendingIntent and then retrieve them using the Intent instance passed to the onReceive of the Broadcastreceiver. Your approach looks okay to me.

What is the problem/error that you are getting? Is "arg1" instance Serializable?

Comment: I'm not getting an error; I'm simply not getting a bundle with the intent that is passed to my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive(Context, Intent) method;  I'm assuming that the intent passed to my BroadcastReceiver is the same intent I create (and populate) in my Activity.  In this case, any argument I want to pass is indeed Serializable.

Comment: Can you show us your code that has/does putExtra(..) and getXXXExtra(..)?

Comment: It turns out I just needed to put the putExtra(...) calls before creating the PendingIntent.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you going to accept any answer or at least going to vote up on any?